# Debian not booting into GUI

Tags: debian, startup, display-manager

My problem is, that my `Debian` installation shows a grey screen on start up and boots into a console, instead into `gnome`.

When I start `X` manually with `startx` everything starts fine, so the DE seems to be functioning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The program where you type your user name and password in a graphical environment, and that logs you into a graphical session, is called a [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)). You need to install a display manager. On Debian, if you install any of the display manager packages then one of them will be started at boot time.

Any of the packages that provide the `x-display-manager` virtual package will do. As of Debian jessie, that's [gdm3](http://packages.debian.org/gdm3) (Gnome), [kdm](http://packages.debian.org/kdm) (KDE), [lightdm](http://packages.debian.org/lightdm) (lightweight but themable), [slim](http://packages.debian.org/slim) (lightweight but themable), [wdm](http://packages.debian.org/wm) (lightweight but themable, oldish), [xdm](http://packages.debian.org/xdm) (old-style, bare-bones). You don't have to use a display manager that matches your desktop environment. If in doubt, pick lightdm.

Comment: i have gdm3 installer, and write in cmd gmd3 start no succes but write in cmd startx load gnome succes, but is in boot the os no running gnome

Comment: @LautaroLinquiman What happens when you run `service gdm3 start`? Copy-paste the output.

Comment: Sorry, then install ligthdm success ok. Thank yo! :)

Answer (score 8):

I was also confused by this problem for a long time. Reading the documentation from Debian wiki, at last, I finally found a way out.

```
# systemctl status gdm

# systemctl start gdm
```

and then I can access GUI again. Reference:

- https://wiki.debian.org/GDM#systemd

Answer (score 6):

First of all GNOME is already there, but by default it is off.

To reset your login manager so that it runs gnome at boot up, do (as superuser)

```
update-rc.d -f gdm3 defaults
```

Or you can re-install and select the proper options

You can install the GUI easily:

```
apt-get install gnome
```

Comment: I'm test your solutions but don´t result.

Comment: Hope you got your solution from @Gilles

Comment: For some obscure reason, I had deleted the gnome package... Thanks for bringing light upon me (and upon my Linux server)   Cheers!

Answer (score -5):

Sometimes this happens if u run out of HD space if u can free some space using "CD" command to navigate through ur directories nd use the "rm 'file'" command to delete the file that can give u some free space then use the shutdown command to exit nd start the PC agin nd it will boot to the GUI. Pis ay

Comment: Please write standard English.