# Unable to start Gnome after installing file-rc

Tags: debian, gnome3

I'm running Debian 8 on my pc. While installing file-rc package, an error occurred and the system crashed. Now the graphical interface won't show up. I tried to find a solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204387/debian-not-booting-into-gui), but all I got was more errors - e.g. failed to get D-Bus connection.

Is there something in the file-rc installation that just breaks Debian?

I'm fairly new to Linux, so it's possible that there's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Not Debian, but Gnome 3, possibly, because it relies on systemd. Before you try to repair anything, log in in text mode and run `dpkg --configure -a` to complete the installation.